# Delete elements of dynamic array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have a dynamic array of integers:

```
int *array = malloc(1000 * sizeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    array[i] = i;
}
```

How can I effectively delete elements between 555-565 without creating new array and copying elements there?

Comment: Copy `0-554` and `566-999` to a new array of `990` elements... Then free the old array.

Comment: You can't! You can just move entries above to the range.

Comment: @LPs: That would not delete the elements, but create a new array.

Comment: @Olaf Well, it was a joke.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the array being dynamically allocated.

Comment: What about a linked list?

Comment: You can't *delete* (as in deallocate memory for) individual elements from the middle of an array, dynamically allocated or otherwise.  The best you can do is what Vlad shows - shift everything from 565 to 999 down 10 spaces, then resize the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could this be accounted as a deletion?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
int* array = malloc(sizeof(int)*110);

for(int i=0; i<100; i++) 
          array[i]=i;

for (int r=56; r<100; r++)
        array[r]=array[r+6];

//memset(array+94, 0, 5);
memset(array+94, 0, 5 * sizeof(int));

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() 
{
    size_t N = 1000;
    int *a = malloc( N * sizeof( int ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i ) a[i] = i;

    size_t n1 = 555, n2 = 565;


    for ( size_t i = n1; i < n2 + 1; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    printf( "\n" );

    memmove( a + n1, a + n2, ( N - n2 ) * sizeof( int ) );

    int *tmp = realloc( a, ( N - n2 + n1 ) * sizeof( int ) );

    if ( tmp ) a = tmp;

    for ( size_t i = n1; i < n2 + 1; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    printf( "\n" );

    free( a );
}
```

The program output is

```
555 556 557 558 559 560 561 562 563 564 565 
565 566 567 568 569 570 571 572 573 574 565
```

Or you can avoid the array reallocation simply by supporting the current number of actual elements in the array.

Comment: at `memmove` and `realloc` , It is not correct size.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks. It is a typo.:)

Comment: It still have **typo**.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I think that now the program does not have a typo.:)

Comment: what means if ( tmp ) a = tmp; ?

Comment: 1) `N - ( n2 - n1 ) * sizeof( int )`  : need brackets.  2) There is a need to move to the end of the element, right?

Comment: @RomaKarageorgievich: Vlad is making sure the `realloc` call succeeded by checking the value of `tmp`; if it's not `NULL`, then the buffer was properly resized, and the (potentially) new buffer pointer is then assigned back to `a`.  If he had assigned the result directly back to `a` without checking and the `realloc` call had failed, then he would have lost his only reference to the previously-allocated memory.